# Java only available on C: Drive unless called by Admin

Tags: java, jmeter

I installed the Java 8 JRE at C:\Program Files\Java\bin and when I call `java -version` on the C: drive I get the expected result.
If I make the same call on the E:Drive, I get the `'java' is not recognized ...` 
 error.

However, if I run the cmd as administrator, I can successfully call Java.

Both my PATH and JAVA_HOME system vars on the E: and C: drives point to `C:\Program Files\Java\bin`

I know this seems very basic but I've never worked with Java and am only using it now for JMeter

Comment: in your path (e.g. `echo %path%`) is there maybe no absolute path for java? E.g. instead of `...;C:\Program Files\Java\bin;...` it contains only `...;\Program Files\Java\bin;...` which would only resolve correctly while on `C:`. The java installers should handle this correctly though, so it would most likely be something you did manually. Uninstalling all java, checking for leftovers and then reinstalling might also help.

Comment: @zapl both path and JAVA_HOME point to full paths C:\Program Files\Java\bin

Comment: What is the output of `where java`? If you installed java with the oracle installer it puts a "special" entry in front of your `PATH` variable.

Comment: @DrHopfen ahhhh... I see someone else had already installed java at C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Comment: @rory that someone is probably the official installer

Comment: What's your os?

Comment: @user726730 Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: It's the java path in enviroment variables? (My Computer --> Properties -->...)